# RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison

Tags: python

**This is my code**

```
def Fibonacci(n):
    if n==1:
        return("Alive")
    else:
        return(Fibonacci(n-1)+Fibonacci(n-2))
        
def AOD(s):
    if(s%2 == 0):
        return("Dead")
    else:
        return("Alive")
n = int(input())
s = Fibonacci(n)
print(AOD(s))
```

**And this is my error:**

```
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison
```

How can I change my code?

Comment: What is the value of `n` that leads to the error?

Comment: Please don't just use random tags. Pick a Python version. This has nothing to do with machine learning or with coding style

Comment: I used n = 3 here

Comment: This question has been mistakenly closed. You need to change the first line of your `Fibonacci` function to `if n <= 1:`

Comment: Yes, this could be debugged by putting `print(n)` as the first line of `Fibonacci`.